# jqlite without jquery - Replacement for $(this) when click children

Tags: jquery, angularjs, find, selector, jqlite

i'm trying to replace all jquery with jqlite so my problem is like this

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <br>
    <div class="childDiv">
        <input type="hidden" id="hdn" value="test1" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="childDiv">
        <input type="hidden" id="hdn" value="test1" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="childDiv">
        <input type="hidden" id="hdn" value="test1" />
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

the div childDiv were added dynamically from javascript

in jquery we can use like this:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#mainDiv')).children('div')
    .on('click', function () {
        temp = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]');
    });
```

i want to replace $(this) since it is a jquery with jqlite like this :
`temp=angular.element(document.querySelector(this)).find('input[type="hidden"]');`
but it doesn't work..please help..any idea?

Comment: `angular.element(this).`

Comment: i've tried it too..but still not working..when i tried to alert it..i got the empty result []

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the id in double quotes, like

```
<div id="mainDiv">
```

Comment: sorry typo..thanks but it didnt solve the problem..ive used double quotes in my code..just typo in this question